# CPLEX: it doesn’t go through the solving process

Tags: c++, cplex

I’ve been trying to solve my math model which i coded in visual studio in C++ language and solve it with cplex. For testing my model i have created a small instance of my input and model works fine and give me optimal solution. I tried to expand the instance size and when i run the code it reads and  outputs my inputs correctly then when it wants to start the solving it freezes. In other word it does not start the solving process with cplex. What do think could be the problem. I have checked my inputs several times.

Comment: I have seen this kind of behaviour from CPLEX when the data is broken, such as having NaNs in the constraints or objective because of divide by zero errors while building the constraints. Try exporting your model as an LP file before you solve it and see if there are some clues in there. Also could give us more info, like what platform, compiler, cplex version etc.

Comment: How to export my model as a LP? 
I am using visual studio 2017 and cplex 12.10

Comment: It is something like cplex.export("filename.lp")